# How to disable the “[…] quit unexpectedly.” dialog in macOS v13 (”Ventura”)?

Tags: crash, development, ventura

I am developing a simple tool in C, and am using assertions for testing. Since I upgraded to macOS v13.0, whenever I run my test suite, I get lots of “*programme name* quit unexpectedly.” dialogue boxes – one for each assertion that failed –, which is quite annoying. Does anybody know whether, and how, those dialogue boxes can be turned off?

I considered whether this question should go on StackOverflow or here, but ultimately it's about how to disable a macOS dialogue box, not about development; this is just for context. If I'm wrong, I'm happy to ask my question over at StackOverflow instead.

### The Problem

The assertions that fail call `abort`, which raises an ABRT signal, triggering an abnormal exit and consequently the dialogue.

For example:

```sh
$ cc -xc - <<EOF
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
        abort();
}
EOF
$ ./a.out
```

triggers

[image: Dialogue box "a.out quit unexpectedly.]

But one of the things that my test suite is testing for is whether the assertions catch the errors they should be catching; those assertions fail on purpose. So it'd be great if I could disable that dialogue box, preferably only for my test suite or only while testing.

### Research

The manual for `abort` states that:

> The abort() function causes a report to be generated by
> Crash Reporter. If you wish to terminate without generating
> a crash report, use exit(3) instead.

So there may be no solution.

I tried `defaults write com.apple.CrashReporter DialogType none`, which reads as if it would disable the Crash Reporter, but to no avail.

I also searched the web, but when my search terms include "Crash Reporter," the only advice I get is to disable sharing crash data with Apple (which I already did); and when they don't, whatever advice might be out there is buried under an avalanche of articles on how to keep this-or-that application from crashing.

### Non-solutions

I suppose, I could re-define `assert` or catch the ABRT signal and call `_exit` from the signal handler, but doing either is bad style, and I'd rather not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Download the “Additional Tools for Xcode NN” disk image (the version matching your Xcode installation) from Apple's [More Downloads](https://developer.apple.com/download/all/) page and start “CrashReporterPrefs.app” in the “Utilities” folder of that disk image.

Here you can select whether the “Unexpectedly Quit” dialog should be displayed never, for application crashes only, or for all crashes of processes run by the user (including command line processes):

[image]

It seems that changes do not take effect until the user logs out and  in again.

If you choose “Basic” or “Server” then execution of the program in the Terminal results in an error message and a non-zero exit code, but no dialog is triggered:

```
$ ./a.out 
Abort trap: 6
$ echo $?
134
```

Comment: Thanks! I wasn’t aware that I had to log out and in again for the change to take effect. For the record, there’s no need for CrashReporterPrefs.app, `defaults write com.apple.CrashReporter DialogType basic` works, too.